# Scoping of params in callbacks with closure

Tags: javascript, callback, closures

I know there have been many questions asked on this topic but I was interested in the difference between two particular scenarios.  Here it is

Scenario 1

```
   //Global Scope
var a=1, b =2;

var callBackFn = function(param3,param4){
    alert(a);             //1  -->defined
    alert(b);             //2  -->defined
    alert(param1);        //3  -->? 
    alert(param2);        //4  -->? 
    alert(param3);        //5  -->defined 
    alert(param4);        //6  -->defined
    alert(localVariable); //7  -->?
}


var classObj = {

    someMemberFunction: function(param1, param2{
        var localVariable; 
        return $.AsyncCallFn(param1, param2).then(function(){
           callBackFn(3,4);
        });
    }

};

classObj.someMemberFunction(5,6);
```

Scenario 2

```
    //Global Scope
var a=1, b =2;

var classObj = {

    someMemberFunction: function(param1, param2){
        var localVariable; 
        $.AsyncCallFn(param1, param2).then(function(param3,param4){
            alert(a);             //1  -->?
            alert(b);             //2  -->?
            alert(param1);        //3  -->? 
            alert(param2);        //4  -->? 
            alert(param3);        //5  -->? 
            alert(param4);        //6  -->? 
            alert(localVariable); //7  -->?
        });
    };

}

classObj.someMemberFunction(5,6);
```

What would be the outputs of the alerts #1 through #6
and more importantly would there be any difference in scenario 1 and scenario 2.

From my understanding in scenario 1 callBackFn will know nothing about param1, param2 and localVariable because it was not created inside someMemberFunction.  But for scenario 2, should someMemberFunction not be aware of param1, param2 and localVariable as well, because it is a closure inside someMemberFunction?

Thanks

Comment: Where are `param1` and `param2` defined? Right now neither of the example would run. JavaScript has *lexical* scope. Meaning that if you can access a variable inside a scope (e.g. `param1`) then any function *defined* in the same scope can access it as well.

Comment: sorry, I have now updated the questions.  Please could you respond back with outcomes of the alerts 1#7. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript has [**lexical scope**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)). Therefore a function (closure) has access to all variables that are *visible* in the scope that it is defined in.

Example 1

```
// This is the global scope
// foo is visible in global scope
var foo = 42;

// bar is defined in global scope, hence it can access foo
function bar() {
   console.log(foo);
}
```

Example 2

```
// This is the global scope
// foo is visible in global scope
var foo = 42;

// bar is defined in global scope, hence it can access foo
function bar(baz) { // baz is defined in the local scope of bar

   // innerFunction is defined in the local scope of bar
   // hence it has access to baz and foo
   function innerFunction() {
       console.log(foo, baz);
   }
}
```

---

Applied to your example:

In scenario 1, `callbackFn` is defined in a scope (global) where `a`, `b` and `classObj` (and `callbackFn` itself) are defined. Hence inside `callbackFn`, `a`, `b`, `classObj`, `param3` and `param4` are accessible.

In scenario 2, the callback function is defined in a scope (`someMemberFunction`) where `a`, `b`, `classObj` are visible and `param1` and `param2` are defined. Hence inside the callback, `a`, `b`, `classObj`, `param1`, `param2`, `param3` and `param4` are accessible.

Comment: Please explain what is wrong with my answer, thanks!

Comment: I am sorry about the down vote but it would probably would have to do with the fact that, the question is specifically asked about - "if there is a difference in the way the callBackFn is defined in 2 scenarios (in1# global scope and 2# inside the .then as an anonymous function), especially pertaining to the scope of "param1", "param2" and "localVariable".

What you have described above is a simple scoping concept for a closure, which is correct, but does not answer this question.

Thanks.

Comment: I have balanced the down voting (by up voting) :-)

Comment: It's true that it does not *directly* answer the question, but it provides all the necessary information needed to draw the correct conclusions. Either way, I added those conclusions for those who cannot (or don't want to) draw them themselves.